# Share javascript and stylesheet files

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, stylesheet

Is it possible to share stylesheets and javascript files between projects in the same visual studio solution. I want to create sort of a base for all my commonly used scripts and stylesheets. So that i can only reference them.

Comment: What i did so far is created an empty MVC Project, that only contain the scripts and stylesheets. If i want to create a new solution i just include this project. When building the ASP.Net Development server creates 2 instances, one for this project and one for the new project. How will i be able to reference the style sheets using 'Url.Content('~/JS/test.js')' ?

Comment: You cannot use the `Url.Content` helper. This helper is intended to be used to resolve only urls that are part of the current application. If you need to resolve external resources you need to use their absolute url.

Comment: Will it be possible to create custom Url.Content Helper where I can pass in the absolute url for the js files. eg Url.ContentFromOtherSolution(jsFileName) ?

Comment: If you already know the absolute url, what's the point of creating a custom helper? What value will this helper add?

Comment: If this solution is deployed the information might differ, that is why i want to create custom helper, so that i can only change one appsetting and all the js files will resolve correctly

Comment: Well, in this case you could write a helper which will read the base url of your CDN from some config file and then concatenate it with the argument being passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to host those files on a web server in order to access them. Just putting them inside a class library that is part of the solution won't make them available to the web project. You could create a CDN in your own network where you will host common static files (js, css, images, ...) that can be reused between multiple web applications.

In order to reference them in your project you need to use their absolute url:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mycompany.com/js/foo.js"></script>
```